# Reclaim disk space after table drop

Tags: clickhouse

Dropping a table that uses hundreds of GBs does not free the disk size it uses immediately.

Is there any way to force Clickhouse to free the disk immediately?

Comment: Consider the call [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/truncate/) before *DROP TABLE*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about database Atomic tables?

https://kb.altinity.com/engines/altinity-kb-atomic-database-engine/

database_atomic_delay_before_drop_table_sec=1

DROP TABLE t SYNC;

or SET database_atomic_wait_for_drop_and_detach_synchronously = 1

Comment: does it require restart clickhouse-server for applying the change?

Comment: database_atomic_delay_before_drop_table_sec -- server setting , needs a reboot.

Comment: database_atomic_wait_for_drop_and_detach_synchronously user setting, does not need a reboot

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-setup-and-maintenance/altinity-kb-server-config-files/